# How to replace a hashtag followed by a number?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I want to replace as `FALSE` where the string contains a `#` followed by an integer.

This is my code:

```
$newlogicexpression = '#1 and (1743327.12 >  10)';
if( strpos( $newlogicexpression, '#' ) !== false ) {
    $newlogicexpression = str_replace('#', 'FALSE', $newlogicexpression);
    $this->logger->debug($newlogicexpression);
}
```

My expected result is: `FALSE and (1743327.12 >  10)`

My current output is: `FALSE1 and (1743327.12 >  10)`

Based on the post method, the integer that follows the # may differ.

The replacement need to happen at any position in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do that.
For example, you can use this regular expression: `#\d+`

Therefore:

```
$newlogicexpression = '#1 and (1743327.12 >  10) and #2';
if( strpos( $newlogicexpression, '#' ) !== false ) {

    $newlogicexpression = preg_replace('/#\d+/', 'FALSE', $newlogicexpression);
    $this->logger->debug($newlogicexpression);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one sensible way to do this -- with `preg_replace ()` -- and you don't need the condition check.  If a number is preceded by a hashtag symbol, the replacement will be made (multiple times if possible).  If the pattern matches nothing, then the input string remains unchanged.

In the pattern, I am using tildes for pattern delimiters.  The `#` doesn't need to be escaped to be intrepreted literally.  `\d` means any digit character (0 to 9).  The `+` means one or more occurrences of any digit.

Effectively, the following substrings would be replaced: `#1`, `#3098426893219`, and `#04`.  Matches can be found anywhere in the string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Oaqgq))

```
$newlogicexpression = '#1 and (1743327.12 >  10)';
echo preg_replace('~#\d+~', 'FALSE', $newlogicexpression);
```

Output:

```
FALSE  and (1743327.12 >  10)
```

---

Update on 2018-12-08:

I'm not entirely sure why I lost an upvote today with no explanation, but if you only want to call `$this->logger->debug($newlogicexpression);` when there is a replacement made, you can use this (still only one function call):

```
$newlogicexpression = '#1 and (1743327.12 >  10)';
$newlogicexpression = preg_replace('~#\d+~', 'FALSE', $newlogicexpression, 1, $count);  // only 1 replace permitted, otherwise use -1
if ($count) {
    $this->logger->debug($newlogicexpression);
}
```